# Getting "skrollr" to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, skrollr

I am a total newbie to JS, but I've been implementing a few things onto my e-commerce site to improve its design. I am trying to have elements fade in and out as they enter and exit the viewport, for which I am using "Skrollr."

However, even though I've followed the directions I found online and think I have the same code as some other sites whose sources I have viewed, I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined(…)

I'm really at a loss for why this isn't working, because I've literally copy-pasted these scripts from other sites where it is. Anyway, as far as I understand it, either (or both) of the skrollr.min.js and skrollr.js files should be defining this variable. I've tried including both files together as well as each individually, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="http://d3a1v57rabk2hm.cloudfront.net/maxjacobson/bold_mobile-copy-8/js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3a1v57rabk2hm.cloudfront.net/maxjacobson/bold_mobile-copy-8/js/skrollr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = skrollr.init();
</script>
```

You can view the site and its full source code here: http://kunstimbrief.com.

I would be extraordinarily grateful for any help. Thanks so much!

Comment: 1. You are loading jQuery too many times 2. try `$(function() {var s = skrollr.init();})` [From documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#lets-get-serious) _...Or you can place it inside the <head> if you want to, but make sure to call init() once the document has been loaded (e.g. jQuery's ready event or even window.onload)._

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mplungjan! I've gotten rid of the extra jquery calls. I tried what you just described, but to no avail: I'm still getting the same error. However, when I put it in, the background image in the two sections I am using a different parallax scrolling script on disappearing and was replaced by white. So despite the error, it seems like it must have been doing something. I took it off, because it was breaking my site, but any further suggestions based on this information? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not seeing any errors. What am I looking for?